# Why isn't attr working in jquery for input?

Tags: html, jquery

Here is my code and I have no Idea why my the password type isn't changing... 
tnx for reading.

```js
$('.btn-show-pass').click( function(){
 $(this).find('i').toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash"); 
 var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));

 input.attr("type", "text");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span toggle='#passInput' class="btn-show-pass"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<input id='passInput' class="input100" type="password" name="password">
```

Comment: It is working: it is changing to `type='text'` in the code you've posted. The only problem is that it does not toggle *between* `type="password"` and `type="text"`: is that what you mean?

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Comment: I doubt... I've just tested it...

Comment: Yeah I mean that...

Comment: Your first step is to try to reproduce the issue, see [mcve].  As provided in an answer and easily demonstratable in a stand-alone snippet, the code *you've provided* works fine - therefore it must be something else that you **have not provided**.  As such, we can only guess - you need to narrow down what's causing the problem and check that the code you provide does indeed demonstrate the problem (which it does not in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To toggle between the input types, you could adjust your code like this:

```js
$('.btn-show-pass').click(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span toggle='#passInput' class="btn-show-pass">click<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<input id='passInput' class="input100" type="password" name="password">
```

Update: As mentioned in the comments, to toggle between the input types was not the real problem. The problem was that the code didn't work on the website. This was caused by an older jQuery version that did not allow to change the type of the input from password to text. Upgrading to a newer jQuery version solved the issue.

Comment: U know i've done this and I know how to toggle... But the code that I've written does't chane the type attr... Toggling is not the point really.

Comment: @ZoZO Then it was a misunderstanding, I thought you meant that. But your code is working well as is shown in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h0gfw4a7/

Comment: Thank u for ur effort lol... ;) I'm confused really... It isn't really working on my webpage I metioned at top in the comments. And in ur fiddle It has no problem.

Comment: @ZoZO I checked your webpage and it's weird that it's not working there. Have you already tried to set it directly using the id instead of reading the toggle attribute: $("#passInput").attr("type", "text"); ?

Comment: Yes I also did that... nothing changed.

Comment: @ZoZO Sounds weird but have you tried to change toggle='#passInput' and id='passInput' into  toggle="#passInput"  and id="passInput" with doublequotes? I know it shouldn't matter but maybe worth a try.

Comment: It made no change... Can we keep in touch in another way ?

Comment: Another idea as I noticed that there is an error when I click the icon that says "Error: type property can't be changed" and comes from jquery. You're using an older version of jQuery, try it with this one instead: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js

Comment: OMG.... Thank u bro... Had no idea and I didn't really think about that... U Saved my day. Anyway why I was using that version(1.7) :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help :) Weird problem but luckily I noticed the error message ;)